# MySQL Query to pull items, but always show a certain one at the top

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database where as items are entered in they're given a section such as "books", "dvds", "posters", "accessories", "clothing" etc. So each item has a section tacked onto it.

Here's the SQL query I'm using to find the unique sections so we can use them to organize the items by section.

```
SELECT DISTINCT section FROM merch
```

That gives me the correct results, putting the unique sections into an array. Now, I'd like for two sections to always be listed first. So I always want "posters" and "books" first and second, then show the rest of the categories.

Is there a way to adjust the above query so that those two sections are shown first, then the remaining unique categories show up below?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT section FROM merch 
    ORDER BY FIELD(section, 'books', 'posters') DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks! Both you and Ryan had the same type of response. But the "DESC" was needed so that the fields I wanted were listed at the top.

Comment: @scatteredbomb: `ORDER BY FIELD(section, 'posters', 'books') DESC, section ASC` to show first `books`, then `posters`, then other sections ordered ASC.

Answer (score 2):

I use the `ORDER BY FIELD()` function when I do this in my application, see below

```
SELECT * FROM merch ORDER BY FIELD(section,'posters','books','dvds','accessories')
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work...

```
SELECT DISTINCT `section`
           FROM `merch`
       ORDER BY FIELD(`name`, 'posters', 'books');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this a couple of ways.

If there is dynamic data in the sections, the easiest is probably a union statement like

```
SELECT * FROM section WHERE id = 'books'
    UNION
SELECT * FROM section WHERE id = 'posters'
    UNION
SELECT * FROM section WHERE id IN (SELECT DISTINCT section_id 
                                      FROM merch 
                                      AND section_id not in ('books','posters'))
```