# Force to order a certain item first

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MySQL Query to pull items, but always show a certain one at the top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557086/mysql-query-to-pull-items-but-always-show-a-certain-one-at-the-top)

Hi I have a number of items in a database table.

At the moments they're sorted by name.

But I have one item with ID 12 which I would like to always be first in the line.

Is this possible in an easy way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do

```
ORDER BY (id = 12) DESC, someOtherColumn
```

This will order by whether `id` equals `12` first (resulting in either `0` or  `1`, hence the DESC to put the positive results first), then any other column(s) you may specify for sorting.

Comment: let me say that this a good solution found so far. Previusly I had used ORDER BY FIELD(field, val) DESC. Is this equivalent to your solution?

Answer (score 0):

Perform two queries. The first query will return only the record with ID=12, and the second query will return all records with an ID other than 12.

```
SELECT * FROM <table> WHERE id=12;

SELECT * FROM <table> WHERE id!=12;
```

Comment: that does work, however: 1st why use two queries? 2nd what if you want to combine more arguments and have a more complex ORDER BY?